# How to automatically add whitespace to WordPress parenthesis in VS Code?

Tags: wordpress, visual-studio

In WordPress, the coding standards recommend using extra whitespace within if/else statements and any other parenthesis like so:

```php
if( is_single() ) { //Added whitespace 
    echo 'foo';
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to achieve this in VS Code. Mine always formats to:

```php
if(is_single()) { // no whitespace 
    echo 'foo';
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I'm using Format HTML in PHP as my formatter.

Comment: Go to Extensions and install "Spaces inside Braces" :

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AiryShift.spaces-inside-braces